# How do you convert a wwn number to the physical Drive ID in ZFS

Tags: raid, zfs

I Have a ZFS pool that has 2 bad drives in it out of the 8. The pool is still accessible yet I do not know how to tell which are the bad drives physically. is there a way to convert the wwn-0x numbers to the drive name and serial number?

jph@HEFFSVR2:~$ zpool status
pool: heffpool
state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices could not be used because the label is missing or
invalid.  Sufficient replicas exist for the pool to continue
functioning in a degraded state.
action: Replace the device using 'zpool replace'.
see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-4J
scan: scrub repaired 0B in 0 days 08:44:20 with 0 errors on Fri Nov 20 21:27:08 2020
config:

```
NAME                        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
heffpool                    DEGRADED     0     0     0
  raidz2-0                  DEGRADED     0     0     0
    wwn-0x5000c5006673d745  ONLINE       0     0     0
    wwn-0x5000039ff4d07b00  ONLINE       0     0     0
    17562097687151423393    FAULTED      0     0     0  was /dev/sdc1
    wwn-0x5000c5006673e232  ONLINE       0     0     0
    865965481153800447      UNAVAIL      0     0     0  was /dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x50014ee26539682d-part1
    wwn-0x5000c50066745273  ONLINE       0     0     0
    wwn-0x50014ee0aea1d297  ONLINE       0     0     0
    wwn-0x50014ee6afcc399e  ONLINE       0     0     0
    wwn-0x50014ee20ce3848a  ONLINE       0     0     0
    wwn-0x50014ee2b793e189  ONLINE       0     0     0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via two steps.  But first, make sure that you have `smartctl` installed.  *However, yours might be better to look for all the good drives, then identify your bad one.*

```
sudo apt install smartmontools
```

Next, get a full directory listing of the `/dev/disk/by-id/` folder

```
ls -al /dev/disk/by-id/
```

It will show you all the `wwn-xxxxxxxxxxxxx` numbers.  Example:

```
ls -al /dev/disk/by-id/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Nov 22 12:47 wwn-0x5000c5003f1afe1e -> ../../sdd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Nov 22 12:47 wwn-0x5000c5003f1afe1e-part1 -> ../../sdd1
```

As we can see mine points to `/dev/sdd`.  Then all we need to do is to get the `smartctl` listing for the drive to help us identify it via a S/N.

```
sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdd
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-54-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Barracuda 7200.14 (AF)
Device Model:     ST500DM002-1BC142
Serial Number:    Z2AF4TL4
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 03f1afe1e
Firmware Version: JC4B
User Capacity:    500,107,862,016 bytes [500 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 1.5 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sun Nov 22 19:42:45 2020 MST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
```

...truncated after top section is all we needed.